# Javascript function not being able to call when sessionStorage value is compared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session-cookies

I am currently creating a flash gallery and every time a new button is pressed to see a new flash I would like to see the page reload to display a new ad. I've troubleshooted the problem with console.logs and have identified that the the sessionStorage variables are being set correctly but when it comes time to call the back/rand/next() functions it just stops in its tracks. Any tips will be of great value.

(Edit) It gets to console.log('Rand button ses received!');

CODE

```
 var flashcon, test, temp;
    var back, rand, next;

    back = document.getElementById('back');
    rand = document.getElementById('rand');
    next = document.getElementById('next');
    flashcon = document.getElementById('flashcon');

    function init() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('ref') == 1) {
            console.log('Back button ses received!');
            back();
        } else if (sessionStorage.getItem('ref') == 2) {
            console.log('Rand button ses received!');
            rand();
        } else if (sessionStorage.getItem('ref') == 3) {
            console.log('Next button ses received!');
            next();
        } else {
            console.log('First time or a reset');
        }

        // Scripts for the buttons
        back.onclick = function () {
            console.log('Back button pressed');
            sessionStorage.setItem('ref', 1);
            location.reload();
        };
        rand.onclick = function () {
            console.log('Rand button pressed');
            sessionStorage.setItem('ref', 2);
            location.reload();
        };
        next.onclick = function () {
            console.log('Next button pressed');
            sessionStorage.setItem('ref', 3);
            location.reload();
        };
    }

    // What switches the flashs
    function back() {
        console.log('Back function');
        sessionStorage.clear();
        if (c == 0) {
            c = paths.length;
        }
        c--;
        displayFiles();
        download();
    }

    function rand() {
        console.log('Rand function');
        sessionStorage.clear();
        if (c == paths.length - 1) {
            c = -1;
        }
        c++;
        displayFiles();
        download();
    }

    function next() {
        console.log('Next function');
        sessionStorage.clear();
        temp = c;
        while (c == temp) {
            c = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
        }
        displayFiles();
        download();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have variables and functions over-riding each others' names.

`back, next, rand` are all function statements which get hoisted above the `... = document.getElementById('...')` for the corresponding variable names.

Change the function names or change the element object names and then try again.

**So basically turn this:**

```
var back, rand, next;

back = document.getElementById('back');
rand = document.getElementById('rand');
next = document.getElementById('next');
```

into this:

```
var $back, $rand, $next;

$back = document.getElementById('back');
$rand = document.getElementById('rand');
$next = document.getElementById('next');
```

and of course edit the matching places following in the code so they point to the right variable.

Comment: Thank you that did solve my problem I don't know why I overlooked that. The site now works except for my back and next buttons which go to the next item in the array to display so that sucks but I'll fix it got any tips for that? My random button works though however.

Comment: I could probably diagnose it if I had more context - the functions reference things that aren't defined in the code you posted (like `c` and `paths`)

Comment: Oh no those things are all good I just didn't include them into the example because they were not needed for the question. The site itself works its just not the math for the next and back buttons which I think since it refreshs every time it can't move forward in the array but the random button can move bc it dosen't matter what flash file it lands on.

Comment: gotcha.  well another thing you might wanna look at is the `next()` and `rand()` function statements seem to be switched (next does a random calculation while rand sets `c` to 0 if it's at the end of paths.length)

Comment: Oh ya I caught that don't know how I switched the names though